# Issue while adding layer as QGIS

Tags: qgis, addlayer

I'm having issues adding a layer. I'm very new to the application, so most likely it's just some basic thing I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to add a Layer (https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.swisstopo.geologie-geotechnik-gk500-lithologie_hauptgruppen/) onto the Swiss map (https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/products/maps/digital_maps/vector/smv500).

The result I want to further work with should look like this: https://s.geo.admin.ch/8a83336eeb

I tried several Layer-Adding-Options and stuff, but more like trail-and-error-style.

Comment: In your links, if you download shape data, and add shapefiles (`.shp` extension) to QGIS by drag & drop (or by opening Vector Layer in the Layer menu), it works.

Comment: I highly suggest you start going through the [official training manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to take the file `Lithologie_Aggregiert.shp` with associated files with same name but different extensions `Lithologie_Aggregiert.*` (in the shp.zip within the `data.zip` file from your first link). You need to add it with "Add Vector Layer".

A shp does not contains style so normally, you need to set the style yourself. Here you are lucky as there are styles for various software included in the data. For QGIS, you need to use the SLD (Style Layer Description) named `2.3_Lithogruppen_V2.sld`
In the layer properties, import the style (see screenshot below to see the entry point)

[image]

Then you choose to "Browse" (right button on "File") and select the SLD file mentioned previously and it's done. See below result

[image]